# PHP download a csv file then 2 files get created

Tags: php, csv

So, whenever the user downloads a .csv file from the site, another .csv file gets created to my ../includes folder so it means there is a .csv file download located inside the downloads folder and another .csv file created where my .php files are located. Is there any way to prevent the file inside my .php files to be created and instead only the download? thanks! here's the code.

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "envoy");
function db_connect() {

  $db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("ERROR!");
  mysqli_select_db($db, DB_NAME);

  return $db;
}

$db = db_connect();
date_default_timezone_set("EST5EDT");
$date = date('m-d-Y,h.i.sa');
$date2 = date('m/d/Y');
$filename = $date.'.csv';
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");

$sql2 = "SELECT sku as Sku,name as 'Brochure Name',location as Location FROM brochureinfo where modified LIKE '$date2' ORDER BY name  ";
$rs2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
mysqli_close($db);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs2);

$seperator = "";
$comma = "";

foreach ($row as $name => $value){
    $seperator.= $comma. ''.str_replace('','""',$name);
    $comma=",";

}
$seperator .= "\n";

echo $seperator;




mysqli_data_seek($rs2,0);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs2)){

$seperator = "";
$comma = "";

foreach ($row as $name => $value){

            $value = str_replace( array( "\r" , "\n", "\r\n", "\n\r" ) ,'' , $value);
            $value = str_replace('</b><br>','',$value);
            $value = str_replace('<b>','',$value);
            $value = str_replace('<br>','',$value);
            $value = str_replace('<br />','',$value);

    $seperator.= $comma. ''.str_replace('','""',$value);
    $comma=",";

    }
$seperator .= "\n";

//putting the heading into the csv file
fputs($fp,$seperator);

}

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$date.csv");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
readfile($filename);

fclose($fp);
```

if it cannot be prevented, maybe a way to change the location where it is created instead of my includes folder maybe another one? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the code saves the CSV to a local file, then reads the file and sends it to the browser. To skip the local creation, comment/remove the `fopen()`, `fputs()`, `fclose()` lines, comment out/remove the `$seperator = "";` line and replace `readfile($filename);` with `echo $seperator;` Also, you have a `echo $seperator;` earlier in the code that has to be removed/commented.

Making your code something like:

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "envoy");
function db_connect() {

  $db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("ERROR!");
  mysqli_select_db($db, DB_NAME);

  return $db;
}

$db = db_connect();
date_default_timezone_set("EST5EDT");
$date = date('m-d-Y,h.i.sa');
$date2 = date('m/d/Y');
$filename = $date.'.csv';
//$fp = fopen($filename,"w");

$sql2 = "SELECT sku as Sku,name as 'Brochure Name',location as Location FROM brochureinfo where modified LIKE '$date2' ORDER BY name  ";
$rs2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
mysqli_close($db);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs2);

$seperator = "";
$comma = "";

foreach ($row as $name => $value){
    $seperator.= $comma. ''.str_replace('','""',$name);
    $comma=",";

}
$seperator .= "\n";

//echo $seperator;




mysqli_data_seek($rs2,0);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs2)){

//$seperator = "";
$comma = "";

foreach ($row as $name => $value){

            $value = str_replace( array( "\r" , "\n", "\r\n", "\n\r" ) ,'' , $value);
            $value = str_replace('</b><br>','',$value);
            $value = str_replace('<b>','',$value);
            $value = str_replace('<br>','',$value);
            $value = str_replace('<br />','',$value);

    $seperator.= $comma. ''.str_replace('','""',$value);
    $comma=",";

    }
$seperator .= "\n";

//putting the heading into the csv file
//fputs($fp,$seperator);

}

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$date.csv");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
echo $seperator;

//fclose($fp);
```

Comment: WOW THIS ACTUALLY WORKED THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! I haven't understood much of this fopen stuffs and just starting to use it. thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the file on the server before sending it. You could just send the headers and then echo the results like this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$date.csv");
header('Pragma: no-cache');


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs2)){
    $seperator = "";
    $comma = "";
    foreach ($row as $name => $value){
        $value = str_replace( array( "\r" , "\n", "\r\n", "\n\r" ) ,'' , $value);
        $value = str_replace('</b><br>','',$value);
        $value = str_replace('<b>','',$value);
        $value = str_replace('<br>','',$value);
        $value = str_replace('<br />','',$value);
        $seperator.= $comma. ''.str_replace('','""',$value);
        $comma=",";
    }
    $seperator .= "\n";
    echo $seperator;

}
//done!
```